# PyQt6 Padding disappears if you remove the down arrow on a QPushButton that has setMenu set

Tags: qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets, pyqt6

I need to delete this default down arrow indicator with setMenu on QPushButton. But If I somehow change QPushButton::menu-indicator style, for example like this:

```
QPushButton::menu-indicator { image: none; }
```

padding from QPushButton disappears immediately. How I can fix this issue?

Little example:

```py
btn = QPushButton("Hello world!")
btn.setStyleSheet(
    "QPushButton { padding: 0 50px; text-align: left; }"
    "QPushButton::menu-indicator { image: none }"
)
menu = QMenu()
menu.addAction("Help")
menu.addAction("Go away")
btn.setMenu(menu)
```

and if I remove the line

```py
"QPushButton::menu-indicator { image: none }"
```

padding appears again

Here are pictures for better understanding:
[image: without menu indicator]

[image: with menu indicator]

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and also the output of `app.style().objectName()` (if you use `app.setStyleSheet()`, call the above *before* that).

Comment: @musicamante same with no styles added just default QPushButton with { padding: 0 14px } and same here if I setMenu on this button and then if I add QPushButton::menu-indicator { image: none; } padding disappears (PyQt6)

Comment: @musicamante I updated post a bit

Comment: Ok, I'm providing an answer, but can you please edit the code and make it a *complete* [mre] (possibly with two buttons, showing both situations)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a bug, as it works as expected in Qt5.

After checking the sources, they changed some important aspects in the computation of the button bevel and subsequent aspects (including the geometry of the label).

I strongly suggest you to [report the bug](https://bugreports.qt.io) as it seems quite important.

In the meantime, there is a partial workaround: you can set a specific QProxyStyle for the interested buttons, and override the [`drawItemText()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstyle.html#drawItemText) function (which is one of the few that are still called on a proxy style even while using a QSS).

This is a possible solution:

```py
class ButtonFix(QProxyStyle):
    def __init__(self, button):
        super().__init__()
        self.button = button

    def drawItemText(self, rect, alignment, palette, 
        enabled, text, role=QPalette.ColorRole.NoRole):
            opt = QStyleOptionButton()
            self.button.initStyleOption(opt)
            opt.features &= ~opt.ButtonFeature.HasMenu
            rect = self.button.style().subElementRect(
                QStyle.SubElement.SE_PushButtonContents, opt, self.button)
            super().drawItemText(qp, rect, alignment, palette, 
                enabled, text, role)
```

Then you can just do something like this:

```py
btn = QPushButton("Hello world!")
# ...
btn.setStyle(ButtonFix(self.proxyBtn))
```

Note that this obviously has some important issues (besides the fact that I just tested it on Linux and on a couple of styles):

- once you explicitly set a style on a widget, setting the application style will have **no** effect;
- in some styles, the padding might not be perfect (I only assumed the margins based on the `SE_PushButtonContents` enum, so it might not be consistent);
- the bug also affects icons, but QStyleSheetStyle does **not** call the base style [`drawItemPixmap()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qstyle.html#drawItemPixmap) (it just calls the QPainter's `drawPixmap()`), so there is no solution for that;

As soon as you know that the bug has been fixed, you can then provide the workaround just for the Qt versions that are affected by it, eventually checking the `QT_VERSION_STR`.